# Is it possible to write Alsa recorder/playback audio in kernel mode?

Tags: c, audio, module, linux-kernel, alsa

I know [how write a program in user mode by using `<alsa/libsound.h>` library in linux.](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6735) But I want to write an application (kernel module) that can record and playback in kernel mode. Any one could help me?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's not something you normally do in the kernel, why do you want to? Just for fun?

Comment: I'm writing a system that some of it's non-functional requirements are kernel-mode specific. We need to record/playback in kernel mode because we don't want to create any process so that user can kill it.